# Creating words by structure

Tags: code-golf, string, random

## Context

As a conlanger, I am interested in creating a uniform, naturalistic language. One of the tricks is to create vocabulary according to certain structures of words. An example from English: In English, we have the word “tap” structured consonant-vowel-consonant. Usually, this means that there are many other words of this structure: “cat”, “dog”, “rock”, “fog”, “good”, etc.

## Task

As input, you have:

- an array `C` containing strings: consonants (`C` is the first letter in the word consonants). Identical consonants cannot be repeated on this list. For example, this list cannot contain ['b', 'b'].
- an array `V` containing strings: vowels (`V` is the first letter of the word vowels).  Identical vowels cannot be repeated on this list.
- string `S`, which contains something like this "CVCCV" (any combination of "C" and "V")

Your task is to replace “C” in the string with a randomly taken string from array `C` and replace “V” in the string with a randomly taken string from array `V` and return (or display) this string.

"randomly" is defined as all possibilities having an equal chance of being selected. This is a kind of simplification: in real languages as well as in conlangs, ​​there are very frequent (for example 'r' in English) and not very frequent sounds but this is just a code-golf.

## Rules

This is code-golf so the lowest byte count wins.

## Examples

```
Input:
C = ['p', 'b', 't', 'd', 'k', 'g', 'm', 'n', 'w']
V = ['a', 'o', 'u', 'i', 'e', 'ä']
S = 'CVCCV'

Output:
pakto
```

```
Input:
C = ['p', 'b', 't', 'd', 'k', 'g', 'v', 's', 'r']
V = ['a', 'o', 'u', 'i', 'e', 'ä', 'ᵫ']
S = 'CVVCCVCCV'

Output:
koebrᵫvtä
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

Takes input as `S`, `[V,C]`

```
Çè€Ω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cPvhFY@a1pxb@f@/c5izcxhXtFJBUklKdnpuXrmSjoJSYn5pZurhJUqxAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>5</s>  4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to Neil!

```
OịX€
```

A dyadic Link accepting a list of characters, `S`, on the left and a list of two lists of characters, `[C, V]`, on the right which yields a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//4e7uiEdNa/7//6/kHObsHKb0P1qpIKkkJTs9N69cSUdBKTG/NDP18BKlWAA)**

If we could take `S` as a list of `1`s and `0`s we'd have the three byte solution `ịX€`.

#### How?

```
OịX€ - Link: S, [C,V]
O    - ordinals (of S)          i.e. 'C':67 'V':86
 ị   - index into [C,V] (vectorises)      C      V   [Jelly indexing is 1-indexed and modular]
   € - for each:
  X  -   random choice
```

Comment: I like both solutions! The 5 and the 3 byte ones +1

Comment: What does Jelly do if an index is out of range? (Charcoal automatically reduces it modulo the range, so I don't need to extract the bit manually.)

Comment: @Neil you just saved a byte - thanks! I even noted in my code break-down that "Jelly indexing is 1-indexed and modular".

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>[92](https://tio.run/##Jc09DoMwDAXgnVNYLCFSxNKtEhNHQGJpGYJJStr8KdBUvU9v0oNRTJdPst6zHd/rHPxp09DAdbPSjZMEFFks57Ks78H4Kkk/BVfjHAyqynLQIYEF4y8IRoNsmhJLUHZRkI9M7hksAy@MiyGt8D@wtfuLC4tMABuJlZiIB3EjHOGJFxuK/tiQNAbiSRhCEd/P3un2DsOMmFkRk/FrpatW9KLjfPsB)</s> <s>[68](https://tio.run/##Jc1NCsIwEAXgfU4xdJNEQlHcFXTTIxS6qUXS9Meo@aFNW7yPN/FgNaObDwbem@df4ebscevhBJftKU3TSpjEbs2SJL07bdkobetMqm5Oq46tlTwnc1Lz3o0gQVuYONHGuzHAP7nl8VVFPRVAGyQgLfJABsQgFllpTcpfQ@LpkBnRSId83jFTxAxVi1ILJQTHrzgeJ4eOHfY8IwB@1DawnhUiFyXn2xc)</s> 61 bytes

Takes input as `S`, `C`, `V`:

```python
lambda s,*w:[random.choice(w[a>"u"])for a in s]
import random
```

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##Jc1NCsIwEAXgfU4xuEkqQRR3Bd30CIVuapE0/QuaH9K0xft4Ew8WM7r5YOC9ee4VJmvOcYAL3OJT6LYTMPP9ltdemM7qg5yskj3banHdLbsmG6wHAcrA3BClnfUB/slYpB81dZQDbZGAdMgDGRGNGGSjDal@DYGnRRZEIT3yeadMmTJUrlKulBAcv@N4mhx7djpmOQFwXpnABlbygldZFr8)! How it works:

The `*w` is used so that the lists of consonants and vowels are packed in a list `w`.

When we do `w[a > "u"]` we are essentially checking if `a` (a character of `s`) is "v" or not. If it is, then `a > "u"` returns `True`, which indexes as `1` into `w`. If `a` is "c", then `a > "u"` returns `False`, which indexes as `0`.

We use those indices to retrieve the correct list of letters from `w` and then choose randomly from that list, picking the list of choices.

Thanks @Arnauld for saving one byte and to @Jonathan Allan for citing [this meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2214/75323), saving me 7 bytes.

Comment: This is what I would've done in my C solution had it not been for that the lists of consonants and vowels are not of equal length.

Comment: I believe that you *should* be able to [take `s` as a list of characters and return the same](https://tio.run/##Pc5LCsIwEAbgfU4xuEkiQRR3Bd30CIVuapE0fQVtEtIX3sebeLCYqeDmg2H@GX73mnprzqGFC9zCUw5VLWEU@zUpvDS1HQ6qt1o1bC3kdTfvSt5aDxK0gbEkenDWT/BLhjT@KKijAmiFTEiNPJAOGRCDrLQk@XYhcbTIjGikQT7vmMm2jMJ5QdSfJW4J1rljnViia9jpyBMC4Lw2E2tZJlKRcx6@) (see [this meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/whats-a-string)) and as such can replace the `"".join(...)` with `[...]`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks for this reference! Shaved 7 bytes :)

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, <s>35</s> 34 bytes

One byte saved thanks to Adam

Prompts for consonants and vowels as continuous strings and the desired output as a comma separated string

```
c←⍞⋄v←⍞⋄C←',c[?⍴c]'⋄V←',v[?⍴v]'⋄⍎⎕
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/4nA5mPeuc96m4pg7OcgSx1neRo@0e9W5Jj1YEiYWCRMrBIGVjkUW8f0KT/QDP@p3EVJJWkZKfn5pVzJaZm5pdyOeuE6TgDYRgA)

Comment: If you liked this golf question, please vote to reopen it.

Comment: If you don't like this golf challenge, please retain its closed state.

Comment: This is the first time I have been lobbied from both sides of a question closure. Personally I had no problem understanding the question and as I got two up votes I assume at least two people agreed with my interpretation and my answer

Comment: By using `⍞` instead of `⎕` you can specify that input shouldn't have quotes, and then use `⎕` instead of `⍎⎕` to save a byte: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/4nA5mPeuc96m4pg7OcgSx1neRo@0e9W5Jj1YEiYWCRMrBIGVjkUW8f0KT/QDP@p3EVJJWkZKfn5pVzJaZm5pdyOeuE6TgDYRgA "APL (Dyalog Classic) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Adám Thanks for the suggestion but whilst it works in Dyalog Classic I cannot get it to work in APL+WIN. If I run the code as you suggest it simply outputs the concatenated code string which needs the second ⍎ to execute.

Comment: @Graham Even if the `C,V,…` is input into a `⎕:` prompt without quotes?

Comment: @Adám It does work!!! Not sure why not before. I simply deleted the quotes around the inputs on my screen and successively hit enter on those lines when required. Finally typing each input when required I get the expected result. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: @Graham Does `v c←⍞⍞⋄C←',c[?⍴c]'⋄V←',v[?⍴v]'⋄⍎⎕` work in APL+WIN?

Comment: @Adám. No it throws an error. It does work if v c are enclosed in parentheses. In which case moving back to ⎕ allows a nested vector of v and c to be entered but we do not save any bytes.

Comment: @Graham Ah right, Dyalog is (unfortunately) lenient with that. Good for golfing, though.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>45</s> 40 bytes

```ruby
->s,*l{s.bytes.map{|x|l[x%2].sample}*''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctBDsIgFIThfU/BxrykQRbu60UIC0BqjKDE12KbtrfxJh4MO26@ZJJ/XqOba9/V45llGxdWbh4Cq2Tzsk5r1NPhZBTblGPYWqKtetEJTZmkIAcGcAF3cAUJPMCbTFP@D4v5BCO4gQC@n73hvSFfvC/UZNFrlkV6U38)

Comment: I didn't think that ruby could outgolf python. Great!

Comment: Ruby code is usually shorter than the equivalent python code.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
⭆η‽§θ℅ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsIwEAXQq2Q3EeIJXElWLkRR6CZkMTalDcakjbF4IHeuPYEn8SSxf/i8z4dpB85t4lDrMftY5Lks1e95lIMSJ44u3eS27KLrnnJS4pCdjxykX@E2tRpjiEkJSuABPOjA9wV/nzdZJQyNWBdQgANX0IMZ3EEmu/yTbhqtEbJ1PYc/) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the input in the form `[V, C], S` where each value can be either a string or an array of characters as desired. Explanation:

```
 η      `S`
⭆       Map over elements/characters
    θ   `[V, C]`
   §    Cyclically indexed by
     ℅  Ordinal of
      ι Current element/character
  ‽     Random element/character
        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 66 bytes

```cs
(C,V,s)=>s.Select(x=>(x<68?C:V).OrderBy(l=>Guid.NewGuid()).Last())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nctNCsIwEAXgvacQN00gZimibQSDiiC6EOpCXMR01GCNkqT@IN7GnWtP4Ek8SXXAEwjD93jDjPZ17U3ZL6yOhz1b7MCpZQ6x3ign2F8bsUpKIlnKPE2E51PIQQdyTgQ5x41mR7ZSyicuA9e9kDwRg8JkfAwnTEIpHykfvlm2KzNnAoyMBeKDM3bN5d5qFciKWDjNF9foELFqtEQCkiFbZI0cEY@46MZ@Lwr7HikQgwDyuqPv5@N7W5NpKiVOjVLaLj8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ËcgV ö
```

Takes input as `S`, `[V,C]`

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=y2NnViD2&input=ImN2dmNjdmNjdiIKWyJhb3VpZeRcdTFkNmIiCiJwYnRka2d2c3IiXQ)

Comment: @a'_' Ok.6 more to go...

Comment: @a'_' By the way, did you like this code-golf question?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica I loved it. But it was blatant that I can't re-open it, because I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104813/discussion-between-victor-vosmottor-thanks-monica-and-a).

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, liking a challenge is not a valid reason to VTR it. Address the issues that led to it being closed and, once done so to the community's satisfaction, it will be reopened.

Comment: @a'_', similarly, *not* liking a challenge is not grounds for closing it or leaving it closed. There have been many challenges here over the years I haven't personally liked, as there have been for everyone - if you don't like a challenge, just skip it and move on to the next one.

Answer (score 2):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) `f` `j`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

Hmm, let's do a pure-ASCII port of that.

```
C[gr
```

### Explanation

````
C    % Convert the string to its codepoints
 [   % Index into the other list
   r % For every indexed item:
  g  % "g"et a random item in this list

Flag:f % Flatten the output list
Flag:j % Join the flattened output list
```
````

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I absolutely can't understand the challenge, so feel free to post your answer so that I can get a better understanding of this. (I guess I'd keep it deleted because I don't know how to fix it.)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>65</s>  64 bytes

```javascript
(C,V,s)=>s.replace(/./g,x=>eval(x).sort(_=>Math.random()-.5)[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc0xDoIwFMbxnVOwtU1qcXEsS2dXFkJMhYJoaUlbkQO5OXsCT@JJqk@Nsy6/5CXvy38vJ@lr149hYWyjYssjFrSgnvDcM6dGLWuFM5Z1dOa5mqTGM2HeuoA3PF/LsGNOmsYOmCzYipTLisTaGm@1Ytp2uMVJmpZoRDRFWyAADXAAOmAADHBCFX0NJFwWOAI9oIDb@f2CRCFEgRJCkr97E@AB90vv6f16@Wah@0nHBw)

Or [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##lc0xDoIwFMbxnVOwtU3qi4tjWTq7shBiKhREoSVtRQ7k5uwJPIknqT6jg5suv@Ql78t/ryblK9eNYWFsrWMjIpU8556JzMOgRjqLTE@qpzMDb12gG5GtVdiBU6a2A2ULWLFiWbJYWeNtr6G3LW1okqYFGQlPyRYJSI0ckBYZEIOcSMlfA4WXRY5Ih2jkdn6/AACRuZQ5KRPGkr@jE@IR90v06f16@Wpj/NOPDw) if we can use an array of characters as I/O.

Comment: The eval trick is really nice! Sadly enough I don't think I can use it in my answer to save some bytes :(

Comment: 55 seems fine unless OP has explicitly said not since I==O and if it quacks like a duck, it is a duck (i.e. [strings *are* lists of characters](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/whats-a-string))

Comment: @a'_' I think I'm privileged enough to hammer this question, which I think would be inappropriate either way.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 68 bytes

```php
function($C,$V,$s){for(;$r=$s[$i++];)echo$$r[rand(0,count($$r)-1)];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxNCsIwEAXgfU/hYmASGkHXsbjIHboJXdT@2CIkIU3diLdx59oTeBJPEvtg@Hg8HhOmkE/nMIWioLHK4@q6NHsnyCiqFS3yMfooNMWKFktzWTZaDt3kiaKNrevFQXV@dUlshdwfZaOfWW@vhOXAascXkEAPbuAK7mABkRtluUX0YAUzGMD3BX@f9zZjU9fG4Fjq/Ac)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 92 bytes

```c
f(s,c,v,m,n)char*s,**c,**v;{for(srand(&s);*s;)printf("%s",*s++/86?v[rand()%n]:c[rand()%m]);}
```

Takes as input a string (`s`), an array of consonant strings (`c`), an array of vowel strings `v`, the length of `c` (`m`), and the length of `v` (`n`).

Could use a temporary variable for the result of `rand` but it wouldn't save me anything.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZFLTsMwEIb3OYXlqsiTGkqyQAjzEMqKbZG6IMoiOElrQZwqToxE1duwY80JOAknCZ5Q@pC6qaX5NB7P/3ukkaczKbuuYIZLbnnJNch5WvuG@750YcWyqGpm6lRn7MSA8I2ARa10UzA6NJT7ZjQaX17c2bhvgaFOruR/XiYgVt1AafnaZjm5Nk2mqrP5recNsrxQOif3k8njwxNLgTCj3vOqwHRM1rm7xOcJgOe5D0mZKs1spTLwlh5xByclvgzihNz0hb8yHrqgnNBnRIPIEC@IGaJEaMQb7TUrsesYHu9oEQZRbxx3LO3BIVPsrxAtQiFyxPfHgbFseKyH48/X5/48bm/RNIqm7lEGnFgX6yXIADa5DQAEWbSNYZSC2CpRulaHTh1u1eGOOtxXr7pf)